# Solving a quadratic trigonometric inequality

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Say I have the following inequality:

$$\cos^2x-\cos{x}>0$$

My books says the inequality is verified for

$$\cos{x}<0\space\vee\cos{x}>1$$

How does one end up to that conclusion?

I know that the inequality above is equal to

$$\cos{x}(\cos{x}-1)>0 \rightarrow \cos{x} > 0 \vee \cos{x}>1$$

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Can you see that $$\cos x- 1$$ will always be negative (or $0$ sometimes)? And to make the product of $\cos x(\cos x-1)>0 $, We must have $$\cos x<0$$

Comment: Awesome, this makes a lot of sense! Is there a mechanical way to do this? Like drawing a grid with all the signs. Say I have multiple factors. Edit: yes - just checked. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, let's take a case of $\cos x( \cos x-\frac{1}{2})>0$ So here you can make a grid of where $\cos x>1/2$, $\cos x<0$ and take the union.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\cos x(\cos x-1)\gt0
&
\implies
\big( \cos x\gt 0\land \cos x-1\gt 0 \big)\lor\big(\cos x\lt 0\land \cos x-1\lt 0\big)
\\
&\implies 
\big( \cos x\gt 0\land \cos x\gt 1 \big)\lor\big(\cos x\lt 0\land \cos x\lt 1\big)
\end{align}
$$

The condition $\cos x\gt 1$ never holds since $\cos x$ always oscillates between $-1$ and $1$. Hence the only remaining possibility is $\cos x\lt0\land\cos x\lt 1$.